# How to rotate object faces using UV coordinate displacement

Tags: uv, displacement

I currently have a single object consisting of 64 faces, each with its UVs as shown in the image.

[image: What I have so far]

I'm trying to rotate each face around the x-axis using the Vector Rotate node, but its stretching the faces, and the angle is all messed up (this gets worse the more it is rotated).

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I suppose that UV coordinates matches real object coordinates.

So you should do these steps:

1. Rotate UV coordinates in 3D space (that's done)
2. Add original offset of each plane
3. Clear existing coordinates aka subtract original coordinates at the end.

How to get each plane offset? If the size of UV equals the size of planes (in my case it is default plane with size 2 so that UV also with size 2), you have to just subtract UV from object coordinates.

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to do the same thing for a more complex object? For example, a sphere consisting of individual faces.